# My shape will not rotate smoothly in processing

Tags: processing

I am trying to connect rotate a shape in processing using serial data from a gyroscope. The shape rotates fine from 0-90 but when the angle is greater than 90 it doesn't rotate until it reaches approx 180. The serial data is correct as I am printing it on the serial monitor. I should note that it does work rarely in the range of 90-180. What can I do.

```
void draw(){

  pushMatrix();
  translate(200,200);
  rotateX(radians(90));

  rotateY(myVal);
  scale(50);
  beginShape(QUADS);


  while (mySerial.available() > 0){
    myString = mySerial.readStringUntil(nl);

    if(myString != null){
  
      background(0.5);

      myVal = float(myString) ;
      myVal = radians(-1 * myVal);
```

Comment: Please post a minimal snippet showing how you receive/parse serial data and how you map that to the rotation in Processing. It might help to actually share how you send the data from Arduino. If you have a separate Arduino sketch that prints the angles via Serial Monitor do the values come out as expected or not ? (it could the that the gyro alone won't cover the full rotations you need, but you might need an IMU (gyro + accelerometer + magnetometer) to merge the data and get better orientation data)

Comment: The issue isn't the values themselves as when i print the values on processing serial monitor i get the correct angles. It's the render that doesn't want to rotate between 90-180 even though the angles are between that range.

Comment: Just to make sure where the issue is: if you `println(myString)` you see the value you expect, and same if you `println(myVal);` right after `myVal = float(myString) ;`) (but before the `radians()` call), right ? Also, regarding rendering, is your mesh still rendering between 90-180 degrees and it's just static for some reason or does it seem to disappear after 90 degrees and reappear after 180 degrees ? If you could share the whole `draw()` routine that would be great

Comment: Thanks for your help Georte. I've managed to figure it out. It turns out the baud rate I was transmitting at (9600) was too fast and the render couldn't keep up with the rate the information was being sent. When I use a baud rate of 2400 it works fine. It still is a bit confusing to me s to why it worked fine between 0-90 but not between 90-180. And yes the mesh is still rendering it was just frozen at 90 degrees and would snap to 180 when it reaches 180 but nothing in between

Comment: No worries. Bare in mind the `while` loop is blocking rendering. I would recommend using `mySerial.bufferUntil(lf)` in `setup()` and `serialEvent()` to parse the serial data. Checkout [this example](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_bufferUntil_.html)

Comment: Thats great. That works with 9600 baud so I think it was the while loop stopping the rendering. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop is blocking the main animation/rendering thread.

An alternative is to pair [`bufferUntil()`](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial_bufferUntil_.html) with [`serialEvent()`](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/serialEvent_.html):

e.g.

```
void setup(){
  ...
  mySerial.bufferUntil(lf);
}
...
void serialEvent(Serial p){
   myString = mySerial.readString();
   myVal = float(myString.trim()) ;
   myVal = radians(-1 * myVal);
}
```